# Overwritten Mage_Checkout controller method to a local module not calling

Tags: magento-1.7, module, overrides, controllers, local

I am overwriting the `Mage_Checkout` addAction() `controller` to my local module.But my local module not called, only `Mage_Checkout` is calling.

**My Code**

config.xml

```
<config>
<!-- modules -->
<modules>
    <Manik_Checkout>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Manik_Checkout>
</modules>

<frontend>
    <!-- overriding Mage_Checkout -->
    <routers>
    <checkout>
        <args>
            <modules>
                <Manik_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">Manik_Checkout</Manik_Checkout>
            </modules>
        </args>
    </checkout>
    </routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

IndexController.php

```
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/IndexController.php';
class Manik_Checkout_IndexController extends Mage_Checkout_IndexController
{
    function indexAction()
    {
        Mage::log("My Action..");
    }
}
```

So, how to solve my problem.How to overwrite core controllers to local module.

Comment: have you created a file called Manik_Checkout.xml under app/etc/modules/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use like below with **routers**

```
  <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>                                        
                      <Manik_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">Manik_Checkout</Manik_Checkout>
                    </modules>
                </args>
             </checkout>             
     </routers>
    </frontend>
```

Also if require in your controller class just add this

IndexController.php should be

```
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/IndexController.php';
class Manik_Checkout_IndexController extends Mage_Checkout_IndexController
{
```

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: sorry @liyakat typo error.I edited..

Comment: still not calling my method..

Answer (score 2):

you are missing the `<routers>`

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <checkout>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Manik_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">Manik_Checkout</Manik_Checkout>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

and in the IndexController.php use this code

```
<?php
    require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/IndexController.php';
    class Manik_Checkout_IndexController extends Mage_Checkout_IndexController
    {
        function indexAction()
        {
            Mage::log("My Action..");
        }
```